MSI installer temporary name in UAC: How to change using 'Set-AuthenticodeSignature'?
I have the same problem as the following questions, i.e. wix created, and signed msi installer is displaying its random name while in UAC. BUT I am not using the SignTool to sign, rather the Set-AuthenticodeSignature, therefore the answers below weren't so helpful. Now, I did read the documentation but there is nothing similar mentioned, like the /d in signtool documentation.
Is there a way to solve this, without, of course, switching to SignTool? Thank you.
Reference questions from 13,12, and 4 years ago: the-uac-prompt-shows-a-temporary-random
odd-program-name-when-installing-signed-msi
numeric-file-name-for-msi-created-with-wix

What's the problem with just using signtool?

I ended up using the signtool after all. The problem was, and is, that this runs in a pipeline. To find where the signtool may reside in each random image, was way too complicated for a mere pipeline. So the fixed path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x64\signtool.exe" is not maybe the ideal solution but it works since this SDK seems to be present in all images at the moment.
